# When to use useState initial value as function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What is the case where you use `useState`'s initial value as a function?
Is there any difference from just passing a value?

e.g.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => someValue)
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You use it when you want the computation of that initial state to happen **only once**.

Because if you use an expression instead say:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(compute());
```

React saves the initial result of `compute()` once and ignores it on the next renders. But the `compute` function is still called on each render. This can be wasteful.

If you pass a function instead, the function is invoked only once.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
> ```
>
> The initialState argument is the state used during the initial render.
> In subsequent renders, it is disregarded. If the initial state is the
> result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function
> instead, which will be executed only on the initial render
>
> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
>       const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
>       return initialState;
> });
> ```

Also, in case you pass function as the argument to `useState` like the question is asking, it must satisfy certain [requirements](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#parameters):

> If you pass a function as `initialState`, it will be treated as an initializer function. It should be pure, should take no arguments, and should return a value of any type. React will call your initializer function when initializing the component, and store its return value as the initial state.

Comment: Why can't we do [state, setState] = useState(compute) ? Does it cause any issues?

@giorgi-moniava

Comment: @B45i You can use that too. I updated the answer also with some info on the requirements on the initializer function.

Comment: Yes, B45i, useState(compute)  vs useState(compute())  are different. The latter is executing the function on each render (e.g. wasteful) the other is passing a function to be executed once by setState (e.g. correct way to do it when you need to compute something once)
|

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use useState's initial value as a function, you need to use currying :

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => () => someValue);
```

This is because in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state), useState executes the provided function and considers its result as the initial value.
Using currying, `() => someValue` is returned and considered to be the intial value.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why wrapping in a function is less computationally heavy is because react will rerun the component function when props change. If useState() has a computation inside like `useState(heavyComputation())`, JavaScript will run heavyComputation(), but in `useState(()=>heavyComputation())`, JavaScript will not run heavyComputation(), but will pass in the curried function, and useState knows not to rerun this function.

#### Normal

Render 1: `useState(heavyComputation()) //JavaScript calls heavyComputation`

Render 2: `useState(heavyComputation()) //JavaScript calls heavyComputation`

Render 3: `useState(heavyComputation()) //JavaScript calls heavyComputation`

...

#### Wrapped in Function (curried)

Render 1: `useState(()=>heavyComputation()) //useState() calls heavyComputation`

Render 2: `useState(()=>heavyComputation()) //useState() uses the value from the previous render so heavyComputation() is not called`

Render 3: `useState(()=>heavyComputation()) //useState() uses the value from the previous render so heavyComputation() is not called`

...

Answer (score 0):

When we have some heavy computation to initialize the state, we should use the function. And this is lazy initialization of the state. Here is a well-written blog on [react state lazy initialization](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-state-lazy-initialization-and-function-updates) by kentcdodds.