# React component doesn't re-render on state change

Tags: reactjs, state, react-functional-component, renderer

i have this **state** in my **Profile.js** functional component:

```
  const [isFollowing, setIsFollowing] = useState(
    user?.followings.includes(proUser?._id)
  );
```

**conditional rendering** based on state:

```
return (
...
 <button onClick={followUser}>
   {isFollowing ? "Unfollow" : "Follow"}
  </button>
...
```

I'm 100% sure that the result of  **user?.followings.includes(proUser?._id)** is **true** but the button still says "follow", so i console log it to see what's happening :

```
 console.log(user?.followings.includes(proUser?._id);
```

the component will re-render 3 times, first time it prints **false**, second time may be either **false** or **true**, the third time it always print **true**, but the state is still false, the component will not re-render on state change and even the state won't change, why is that happening and how to fix it?

**followUser function** in case you want to take a look:

```
  const followUser = async () => {
    if (isFollowing) {
      await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/unfollow-user/${id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: user?._id,
        }),
      });
      dispatch({ type: "UNFOLLOW", payload: id });
    } else {
      await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/follow-user/${id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: user?._id,
        }),
      });
      dispatch({ type: "FOLLOW", payload: id });
    }

    setIsFollowing(!isFollowing);
  };
```

Comment: Can you share implementation of followUser function?

Comment: Try updating the state by calling the `setIsFollowing` and not when declaring the state, so: `if(user?.followings.includes(proUser?._id)){setIsFollowing(true)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial state will be disregarded for subsequent renders. You must use `setIsFollowing(user?.followings.includes(proUser?._id))` instead.

Put it into `useEffect` and it will work.

Comment: you can also do the following: `const [state, setState] = useState(() => () => someValue);` source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68274218/16168626

Comment: this way you will put a function that generates your state and will have to call it each time you want your state: `state()`, right? Doesn't seem to be a nice solution as each state access requires new computation.

Comment: that's a good point.