# What is the exact behaviour of useRef react hook? Does the object get recreated on each rerender?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating an app where I need  to create an object on initial render and keep it for the whole component life.

My code looks somehow like that right now:

```js
function Component() {
  const obj = useRef(new Smth());
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={obj.current.p}>p</button>
      <button onClick={obj.current.c}>c</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The React documentation says:

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

from: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

and it seems that I use it properly. Yet, Hooks FAQ says:

> You might also occasionally want to avoid re-creating the useRef() initial value. For example, maybe you want to ensure some imperative class instance only gets created once:

```
function Image(props) {
  // ⚠️ IntersectionObserver is created on every render
  const ref = useRef(new IntersectionObserver(onIntersect));
  // ...
}
```

> useRef does not accept a special function overload like useState. Instead, you can write your own function that creates and sets it lazily:

```
function Image(props) {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  // ✅ IntersectionObserver is created lazily once
  function getObserver() {
    if (ref.current === null) {
      ref.current = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersect);
    }
    return ref.current;
  }

  // When you need it, call getObserver()
  // ...
}
```

from: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

So does the initial value get recreated or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So does the initial value get recreated or not?

Yes the initial value can be re created but then it is *ignored*.
For example here:

```
function Table(props) {
  // ⚠️ someFunc() is called on every render
  // But after first (or maybe second render if it is strict mode) it's value is ignored
  const rows = useRef(someFunc(props.count));
  // ...
}
```

It is [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60120261/when-to-use-usestate-initial-value-as-function/60120302#60120302) with `useState`, if you pass a value to its constructor it gets recomputed but then it gets discarded. You can pass function to `useState` which will only be executed once. Apparently based on the docs, `useRef` doesn't have such option. But you can [simulate](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-create-expensive-objects-lazily) it:

```
const ref = useRef(null);

// ✅ IntersectionObserver is created lazily once
function getObserver() {
  if (ref.current === null) {
    ref.current = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersect);
  }
  return ref.current;
}
```